# Why can we approximate a sum by a definite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation

From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals, I read that

$\int_{s=a-1}^{b} f(s)\ ds \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{s=a}^{b+1} f(s)\ ds$ for increasing function $f$

and

$\int_{s=a}^{b+1} f(s)\ ds \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{s=a-1}^{b} f(s)\ ds$ for decreasing function $f$.

However, I don't understand why this holds. Inside the summation $ \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i)$, we are summing up $f(i)$ at particular points $a \leq i \leq b$, while the integral $\int f(s) ds$ is the area under $f$. How can "points" be equal to "area"? I don't understand...

Can anyone please help clarify? Maybe some visualization will help me.

Comment: Are you familiar with Riemann sums?

Comment: A little bit, but isn't Riemann sum $\sum_{i=a}^b f(i) \Delta_x$? There is no $\Delta_x$ here, so how can $\sum_{i=a}^b f(i)$ be an area?

Comment: ohh is the $\Delta_x$ just 1 in this case?

Comment: $$ f(j) = \int_j^{j+1} f(j) \mathrm d x = \int_{j-1}^j f(j) \mathrm dx. $$

Comment: got it!! I understand now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Let $g(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ and $h(x)=f(\lceil x\rceil).$ Then $$\int _{a}^{b+1} g(x) \,dx =\sum_{i=a}^b f(i).$$ and a similar sum for an integral with $h(x).$